# python internal - how to really create a function

Tags: python, types, internals, syntactic-sugar

I'm Trying to learn more about python and how it works

If we want to declare a function in python. We do this

```
def bar():
    print("my great bar function")
bar()
```

I'm told that under the hood of python, this corresponds to

```
class bar():
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("my great bar function ")
a =bar()
a()
```

But `class bar()` is only syntax sugar for

```
bar = type("bar",(object,),{"__call__":Placeholder_for_source_code})

a= bar()
a()
```

I'm trying to replace the Placeholder_for_source_code in the body of type with the source code for printing "my great bar function". When i inspect `bar.__dict__['__call__']`

all i get back when i inspect the class bar above is `<function bar.__call__ at 0x00000000035B37B8>`
Can somebody tell me how to this works.

Comment: Are you asking what "Placeholder_for_source_code" should be replaced with? if so, then it should be replaced with a callable, for example `bar = type("bar", (object,), {"__call__": lambda self: print("my great bar function")})`

Comment: yes, that's what im asking, and that works , But lambda,is  just creating a function which could be replaced with its own type and call method?

Comment: "I'm told that under the hood of python, this corresponds to" - this is utterly wrong, where did you hear this?  Beyond the obvious nonsense of defining a function in terms of something that *contains exactly the same function*, there is certainly not a new type/class being created for each function.  ALL functions are instances of a single existing type, which is accessible as `types.FunctionType`; what they contain is not yet another function, but a *code object* containing the compiled bytecode representation of the function.  (You can create these yourself with the `compile()` built-in.)